# Proxy Service & Business Service

Tags: oracle, service, soa, bus, oracle-service-bus

Can i use a proxy service without a business service while configuring message flows in Oracle service bus? If so is what scenarios would we use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a proxy service that does not use a business service.

Some reasons for such an approach is to create a common proxy module that is used by other proxy services that may do some common message processing before forwarding to a business service.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot create a proxy service without a business service call in OSB, but you can call dummy business services that publish on a JMS topic that nobody listens on. This kind of proxy service could implement data transformation (e.g. XSLT) between the request and response, or enrich the response with data retrieved from a lookup table (fn-bea:execute-sql()).
A service bus, like OSB is meant to provide a façade to back-end (business) services: route to and compose existing services. What you are asking for is to create new back-end services which is more suited for Java EE servers or Oracle BPEL.

Update: You can create stand-alone proxy service, if you use pipeline pair and stage, but no route steps.

Comment: Thanks Miklos,
Even i thought the same thing but you can always have a proxy service with only a pipeline pair(hence BS is not required), but then the basic question that remains is when do you use a pipeline pair and when do you use a route node, I am very much a newbie to SOA, the ALSB docs only talk about configurations without emphasizing on the "WHY?"..Would really appreciate if you could direct me to some good links if you know..

Comment: You are right, I haven't used OSB (ALSB) for a year now, and I did not remember you can create a proxy service without a route step. Of course in this case it is not a real 'proxy'. OSB can be useful when a company builds SOA, but by no means necessary or enough. SOA is as much a business and organizational paradigm as technical. You can learn about SOA on the website http://whatissoa.com. Regarding OSB best practices, I cannot recommend any links. Try google 'ALSB best practices'. Oracle has at least 2 OSB training courses (programming and administration) but I've not attended them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a proxy service without a business service. A simple scenario is suppose you want to fetch the data from the queue, could be jms or mq, and you don't want to do anything with that data. You just simply want to empty the queue and do not want to store the message. In this case, your purpose can be fulfilled by simply creating a proxy service.